# Moderncv line spacing variation in different sections

Tags: fonts, moderncv, line-spacing

I'm updating my résumé using moderncv casual, and I'm encountering a weird phenomenon:
The line spacing, and font size of the description in "Master Thesis" are different than in "Experience". Unfortunately, I am unable to find where to change those parameters for the whole document to be consistent in both line spacing and font size.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image: Using the template from moderncv v2.0.0 2015-07-28]

I must admit that LaTex styles are still a mystery to me...

Thanks for you help, guys!
Cheers

Code example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Prof. X and Dr Y}
\cvitem{description}{\lipsum[1]}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}
Detailed achievements: \lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

Is this only a difference of font and spacing between \cvitem and \cventry? If so, how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is hardcoded in the *.sty file.
When looking at the moderncvbodyi.sty you'll find the following:

```
  \renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%   \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

and:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Clearly \cventry uses a minippage-environment with small fonts. You could change it by removing the "\small"-command from the *.sty file or by simply changing your code to

```
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{\normalsize{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}
Detailed achievements: \lipsum[1]}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! It does the trick perfectly!